# Setting the title of a .pdf served by asp.net from the file name in a c# handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse

I use this code to attach a file to a response:

```
context.Response.ContentType = MimeTypeMap.GetMimeType(fileExtension);
context.Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + MyTable.Rows[0]["DG_OriginalFileName"].ToString());
context.Response.WriteFile(myfile);
```

The file is opens in a new tab but the title of the tab is the handler name and not the file name.

[image: screenshot_served_file]

Comment: The code given here is not descriptive enough to give an elaborate answer but I would guess from general standards that the title could be set in a metadata object which should be accessed in the context.

Answer (score 0):

If it is **just** your intention to display the correct filename without the extension you could edit the line

```
MyTable.Rows[0]["DG_OriginalFileName"].ToString()
```

to:

```
MyTable.Rows[0]["DG_OriginalFileName"].ToString().Substring(0, s.Length - 4);
```

This however is **not** a clean solution and you should invest some time into refactoring the accessor `MyTable.Rows[0]["DG_OriginalFileName"]` to a meaningfull object with a `Title` attribute.